# Apply a list of parameters to a list of functions

Tags: scala

I have a list of parameters like `List(1,2,3,"abc","c")` and a set of functions which validates the data present in the list like `isNumberEven`, `isAValidString` etc.

Currently, I take each value of the list and apply proper function which validates the data like `isNumberEven(params(0))`. This has led to big and messy code which is completely imperative in thinking.

I am expecting that it should be possible to do something like this in Scala -

```
List(1,2,3,"abc","c").zip(List(fuctions)).foreach{ x => x._2(x._1)}
```

However, this fails giving a runtime exception of type mismatch:

> error: type mismatch;
>   found   : x._1.type (with underlying type Any)
>   required: Int with String

I tried pattern matching on Function traits but it fails due to type erasure.

Any pointers will be appreciated as how can this be solved.

Comment: You may know that the types line up, but the compiler doesn't. If you go this route, you're making it impossible for the compiler to help you. There are always much better ways of modeling a list of parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very naive and non extensible implementation, I'm not very good with types, surely there's a better way:

```
val c = List(1,2,3,"abc","c")

def isEven(x: Int) = if(x % 2 == 0) true else false

def isUpperCase(x: String) = if(x.head.isUpper) true else false

c.map {
  case x: Int => isEven(x)
  case x: String => isUpperCase(x)
  case _ => false
}
```

You could also define list of functions:

```
scala>   val c = List(1,2,3,"abc","c")
c: List[Any] = List(1, 2, 3, abc, c)

scala>   def isEven(x: Int) = if(x % 2 == 0) true else false
isEven: (x: Int)Boolean

scala>   def isOdd(x: Int) = !isEven(x)
isOdd: (x: Int)Boolean

scala>   def isUpperCase(x: String) = if(x.head.isUpper) true else false
isUpperCase: (x: String)Boolean

scala>   def someString(x: String) = true
someString: (x: String)Boolean

scala>   val ints = List(isEven(_), isOdd(_))
ints: List[Int => Boolean] = List(<function1>, <function1>)

scala>   val strings = List(isUpperCase(_), someString(_))
strings: List[String => Boolean] = List(<function1>, <function1>)

scala>   c.map {
     |     case x: Int => ints.map(f => f(x)).exists(f => f(x))
     |     case x: String => strings.map(f => f(x)).forall(f => f(x))
     |     case _ => false
     |   }
res2: List[Boolean] = List(true, true, true, false, false)
```

Comment: I'm guessing the OP wants to have a variable list of functions passed. SO there may be several different validations for each String, several others for Ints etc.

Comment: Uhm, you can combine function that returns Boolean, like `isUpperCase && !isNumeric` in the same case, or am I missing something?

Comment: of course you can. But then the code is inflexible. What happens if you want to run one set of validations on one call of this code, and another set on another call? A list of validation functions is perfectly good way of achieving this.

Comment: @Paul yes, I understood after what you meant, I made an edit.

Comment: OK. I'm not sure if the OP wants separate lists per type (because it's not dynamically extensible to additional types), but if that isn't wanted and a mixed-type list of values are also wanted then the OP isn't too bothered about type checking anyway :)

Comment: Isn't `ints.map(f => f(x)).contains(true)` the same as  `ints.exists(f => f(x))`. And `!strings.map(f => f(x)).contains(false)` is `strings.forall(f => f(x))`?

Comment: @Paul well then if he doesn't want different lists per type it would mean to have a list of functions which have to check for the type of a variable since you will be passing an `Any` (or an `AnyVal`) and return some filterable value since if the type doesn't conform to the method validation, the validation itself wouldn't matter. I'm not sure how would I go about that. You are right, your way of composing exists and forall is more legible.

Comment: Right, that's what I meant about not caring about types. Anyway, SO is whining this is an extended discussion so I'll stop for now

Comment: Thanks. It is not exactly what I want but it seems that's the best that can be done without complicating the code much.
@Paul - Thanks for the discussion. You understood exactly what I wanted :)

Answer (score 2):

I just want to present a different approach without matching, although it is certainly sledgehammer-like.

First all functions are converted to functions of type `Any => Boolean`.

It iterates over the values in `c`. For each element it tries to find a function that is applicable and that results in true. If it doesn't find one, false is yielded.

```
def isEven(i: Int) = i % 2 == 0
def isGreaterThanTwo(i: Int) = i > 2
def hasB(s: String) = s.exists(_ == 'b')

def convert[T](func: T => Boolean) = (a: Any) => func(a.asInstanceOf[T])

val functions = List(isEven _, isGreaterThanTwo _, hasB _)
val c = List(1,2,3,"abc","c")

val result = {
  val convertedFunctions = functions.map(convert)

  c.map(elem => convertedFunctions.exists(func => Try(func(elem)) getOrElse false))
}
```

with the result `List(false, true, true, true, false)`.

The upside is that you can have as many functions as you like and it is therefore extensible. The downside is that you rely on exceptions. (which is usually not a good practice)

I first tried a solution with converting to `PartialFunction` and modifying the `isDefined` methods so it can be called on `Any` but then checks for a certain type. Then a lot of type-erasure happened and I couldn't make it work. Maybe that could be worth a shot.

If that is possible the code could be changed to:

```
def convert[T](func: T => Boolean) = new PartialFunction[Any, Boolean] {
  def isDefinedAt(x : Any) = ??? //check if x is an instance of T, type erasure problem
  def apply(x : Any) = func(x.asInstanceOf[T])
}

val result = {
  val convertedFunctions = functions.map(convert)

  c.map(elem => convertedFunctions.exists(func => 
  func.isDefinedAt(elem) && func(elem)))
}
```

which looks pretty nice.

Comment: I was initially using your approach (except for the Try part). The problem was for me that validation function that takes a parameter which doesn't conform to their signature shouldn't return true or false because then a failed validation would be equal to a non applicable validation which is from a certain perspective wrong, they should have some custom result that can be filtered out after since the false they return is not the same as the one returned by a validation function.

Comment: I agree that there is a difference, but there is no specification from OP and that's why I chose to make it simple.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely certain on how you're planning on using the data afterwards, because 'foreach' would not actually return anything. But maybe this pattern-matched solution can help you achieve what you want?

```
scala> val f1 = (x:Int) => false
f1: Int => Boolean = <function1>

scala> val f2 = (x:String) => true
f2: String => Boolean = <function1>

scala> List(1,2,3,"abc","c").map {
    case x:String => f2(x)
    case x:Int => f1(x)
}
res3: List[Boolean] = List(false, false, false, true, true)
```

Comment: Thanks but the code is inflexible for my needs.Lets say, I will like to apply f2(x) to String "abc" and f3(x) to the last string. That will not work.